# Getting rid of temp-xxxx.rdb files

Tags: git, redis

When starting redis from a directory with a `redis.conf` that includes:

```
save 60 10000
dir ./
```

it saves a temporary `temp-1234.rdb` (with the number always changing) to keep persistence. Problem is, I fire up redis-server from inside my git repo and these temp files are generated there and show up as untracked.

**Is there a way to keep redis from generating them (or generating them elsewhere)?**

**Or should I just add them to `.gitignore`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default of `dir ./` (current working directory) in `redis.conf` to somewhere outside of your git repo.

```
# For default save/load DB in/from the working directory
# Note that you must specify a directory not a file name.
#dir ./
dir /home/octopus/redis_server/
```

Comment: do you know if it accepts `~` instead of a hardcoded home path?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Redis Persistence strategy by config the .conf file. but the temp-****.rdb  will always locate in the same dir path which is ./ by default.

the numeric **** indicates the pid who belong to the process forked by redis server to save the DB on disk, a atomic rename is engaged after work completed. it exists just a while with the old rdb file.

whether you should add them to .gitignore depends your opportunity when execute "git add ****". it chance to include when bgSaving is working just now.  Of cause you could make such a rule with no harm only if you guarantee it excludes other normal files.

look up the rdb.c in redis src directory:

the line "snprintf(tmpfile,256,"temp-%d.rdb", (int) getpid());"

```
 /* Save the DB on disk. Return REDIS_ERR on error, REDIS_OK on success */
int rdbSave(char *filename) {
    dictIterator *di = NULL;
    dictEntry *de;
    char tmpfile[256];
    char magic[10];
    int j;
    long long now = mstime();
    FILE *fp;
    rio rdb;
    uint64_t cksum;

    snprintf(tmpfile,256,"temp-%d.rdb", (int) getpid());
    fp = fopen(tmpfile,"w");
    if (!fp) {
        redisLog(REDIS_WARNING, "Failed opening .rdb for saving: %s",
            strerror(errno));
        return REDIS_ERR;
    }
```